# Pacing, Moving Labels. Save images

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, runtime

Firstly I want to apologize for my bad English skills. I will try to express myself at much as clear, but if there is something that you can't understand - ask me, I will try to say it correct.

Now lest go back to my questions. I was wandering how to title my questions, because I have a bunch of it. Here is the introduction to my problem.

I am working on Windows Form Application, using C#.  I have to make a program, which create a matrix for business modeling (this economic this are really unknown for me). Requirements are: Menu(File>New/Open/Save/Save As/Exin; About Form). The user should be able to create a coordinate system (done), edit the X/Y labels (I think it done), creating a matrix, inside the coordinate system, save the image as *.jpg and *.bmp.

[Here](http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/85319246/file.html) I will upload my project. I am using a VS 2012.

Now the questions:
1) How can I erase the coordinate system when the user choose File>New
2) Can labels be moved run time by the user?
3) How can I save everything like *.jpg & *.bmp

If I have to explain something, to add more info or whatever, just tell me.

P.S - I want to notice, that I am not waiting for someone to give me already done and working code. every kind of idea or something will be really helpful.

Comment: drawing everything yourself would have the best performance, that way saving image is also easier if your `canvas` exceeds the `Form's ClientRectangle`. Otherwise (using `Label` controls), the performance will be worse when the number of controls grows, saving image when the `canvas` is large (so that the scrollbars appear) is also not easy (I guess `DrawToBitmap()` won't work expectedly in that case)

Comment: Okay, but I have to be able to move, edit the text. In addition I will have maximum 11 labels, not more. I will try to DrawToBitmap() and I will see what will happen. Thanks for the advise.